# get EXEDIR to show mapped path not UNC but still have admin rights, nsis

Tags: nsis, uac

I'm creating an installer with NSIS.

It does exactly 2 things.  Creates a shortcut to an executable, and puts a dll in the system32 directory.

I have to request admin elevation to achieve the copy into system32 for the dll's

However when its running with admin rights the mapped drive disappears and becomes a UNC path.  I want to keep it the mapped drive path though.  Some internet research shows that when elevated to admin UNC paths replace mapping which are user specific.

How can I achieve both in the same install?

Answer (score 0):

Mapped drives are per logon-session (token) and UAC uses a split-token model when elevating so there are no ways around this. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2007/02/19/mapped-network-drives-with-uac-on-windows-vista.aspx) for more details.

You could elevate cmd.exe and map the drive again before running setup...

Comment: Is there a way to keep it at user privilege and then use some other workaround to install files into the system32 directory?

Comment: Maybe. What does $ExeDir have to do with a shortcut anyway?

Comment: The objective is to create a shortcut to a file in that same directory that the install was run from.

Comment: That does not make sense (IMHO). $ExeDir is useful if the installer is on a CD/DVD ROM and you need to copy/extract external files during the installation. It should not be used as a destination for anything, only a source. A standalone installer .exe can be located anywhere; %temp%, temporary internet files and even in directories where you don't have write access...

Comment: This one is guaranteed to be in the right place.  Its not a typical installer.

Comment: You could probably nest installers and set the outer installer to RequestExecutionLevel user and pass $ExeDir as a parameter to the inner installer when calling ExecShell.